# Should I avoid Constants folder in Swift

Tags: swift

I have `viewcontroller` and constant property as below. I want to use tableViewRowHeight in my vc again to avoid using like `tableView.tableViewEsmimatedRowHeight = 100`

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

   // MARK: - Constants
    private struct Constants {
        static let tableViewRowHeight: CGFloat = 100
    }

}
```

or

I should create a group folder named constant ? Which is the best solution in terms of safety and being clear my VC otherwise optimum way ?

Comment: If you have many constants, it's better to create a separate file name as Constants.swift . There you could write struct for different types of constant. then call by using Constants.structName.Property. It will increase code readability

Comment: @alamin39 it won't increase code readability. Always put constants where they belong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example, the approach would be:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tableViewRowHeight: CGFloat = 100
}
```

or

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var tableViewRowHeight: CGFloat { 100 }
}
```

Either is fine.

There is no reason to separate this out as a "Constants" type. There is no need to make it static.

Row height is specific to a table view. It's not like when you change one table's row height, you'd want to change *all* the tables in your program. So you wouldn't want to pull that out into anything. It is fine to name it and put it in a section of your specific ViewController just so you can find it easily, but creating a type called "Constants" doesn't buy anything.

What if you *did* want to vary some aspects across your whole system, though? Maybe a body font or a highlight color that if you change for one view you want to change for all views. Then it could make some sense to have a type for that. But it still wouldn't be some vague name like "Constants." In most cases it's actually nicest to do that by adding extensions on the thing you want:

```
extension UIColor {
    static var corporateHighlight: UIColor { .green }
}
```

That means when you use it, you can just call it `.corporateHighlight`. That said, I highly recommend you look at Asset Catalogs instead.

It is rare in my experience that spacing or heights make sense to do this way. But if when they do, it often makes more sense to create a UITableView subclass that overrides `rowHeight` rather than have a constant somewhere for it. That way you can name the UITableView to indicate how these tables are "the same" in some way. (Again, it would make no sense to set a single row height for every table in the program.)

I also sometimes like Visal Rajapakse's solution of putting this information on the cell rather than table. Sometimes that works; sometimes it doesn't. But it captures the same idea of having a type that represents cells that have something in common and should vary together.

You should never have a global thing called "Constants." That's too broad and breaks code reuse. Even if you eventually did need something to hold values, you'd want to put it into something like Style. Having a single place that you list all the cell paddings and also all the network timeout values and also the number of password retry attempts is just a dumping ground for random global values. It's rare that you want to put constants outside the type they are most used in. It is even more rare that you want them to be global on that scale.

Answer (score 1):

#### Tableviews

You can create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. For instance,

```
class RootTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // Get only height property
    static var height: CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
}
```

And inherit from `RootTableViewCell` to cells you want a height of 100 like follows

```
class CustomCell: RootTableViewCell {
   
}
```

Which will make `height` accessible to all the cells that subclass from `RootTableViewCell`.

#### Constants for general use

If you use `height = 100` else where, the best option is to create a `Constants` class and have nested `structs` for each of the functionality you want. For example,

```
struct Constant {
    struct Cells {
        static let height: CGFloat = 100
    }
}
```

Usage of this will be,

```
cell.frame.size.height = Constant.Cells.height
```

#### Using a code generator

The final option is to use a code generator. A popular option is [SwiftGen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen), which makes things so much easier when you have configured it for your project. It will automatically generate all the constants such as `UIImages`, `UIColor`, nibs, etc. for you

Comment: by the way, a handy way for wrapping constants is an  empty `enum`, not a `struct`. I would advise to never have something called `Constants`, there is always a better place to put the constant instead of some generic file called `Constants`.  That's not the best option, that's always the wrong option. I cannot agree more with a constant height put into a specific cell, although in most situations the height should be declared in xib.